# Performance of align-items: stretch vs alternatives

Tags: performance, css, flexbox, css-grid

In my current project, there is a performance constraint on tolerable loading times, and test deployments have demonstrated that lag is significant enough for me to look into code optimisation.

While researching on the performance of CSS flexbox, my understanding is that it is faster than both the old flexbox implementation and CSS tables ([Source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow)). When comparing between flexbox and the new up-and-coming CSS Grid ([Source](https://blogs.igalia.com/jfernandez/2015/06/24/performance-on-grid-layout/)), grid performs better in 2D layouts, which is only to be expected since it's designed for that as opposed to flex which is designed for 1D layouts.

However, when it comes to 1D layouts, grid performs better than CSS flex when the latter uses `align-items: stretch` (the default value for this property). When `stretch` is not used though, flex performs better.

So therein lies the question: stretch alignment is useful but has a significant impact on performance (which is important to me because of my project's system's heavy use of iframes and nested flexboxes within each frame). Will it therefore improve performance if I don't use stretch and replace it with other alternatives (e.g. `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` depending on the flex direction) for specific elements that do not already fill up the whole space without stretching?

Comment: Not sure how we're supposed to know what the performance hit will be when using percentage widths / heights vs `align-items: stretch`. You seem to be good at testing performance. Maybe you can let us know...

Comment: And `align-items: stretch` is the source of an important flexbox feature: *equal height columns*. If you remove that setting your gain in performance may come at the expense of functionality.

Comment: @Michael_B I'm not a performance testing pro - it's pretty obvious when you need to fully load within 10 seconds and it's taking many seconds longer lol

Comment: @Michael_B I am aware of the possible loss of functionality. My question, in part, is asking if there are any alternatives worth considering and whether such alternatives offer better performance. To me it is an acceptable answer if the functionality is not feasibly replicable or that `stretch` already provides the best performance when it's functionality is needed.

Comment: Wow. You're dealing with 10-second+ loading times? Forgetting about the layout's appearance, what happens when you switch everything to `align-items: flex-start`?

Comment: @Michael_B Well to be fair, the presence of multiple iframes was the main issue because of all the DOM blocking. I have already resolved it so loading time is much better now. Nonetheless, I still ought to do what I can because we have only addressed the lag on local test servers and not on the client's actual environment yet - and we have a map module that is not finished so the loading time is still expected to increase as the scope of functionalities approach completion.

Comment: You may want to consider display: table/table-row/table-cell